# SagePay responsive card selection page

Tags: php, opayo

I have been given a task to update our current SagePay card selection page to responsive design.

In their [integration and protocol guidelines](http://www.sagepay.co.uk/file/21086/download-document/FORM_Integration_and_Protocol_Guidelines_130515.pdf?token=LtnTL0y65s_nnHIYwecwI1ZWC2Lc0UHf4rXlzjkJi9w) document there are screenshots of responsive card selection page but I can't seem to find any information on how to set it.

I have also tried their PHP integration kit that is located [here](http://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/find-an-integration-document/form-integration) but the card selection page doesn't seem to be responsive.

Has anyone come across this?

Comment: Please share your code what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to be sending transactions over at a protocol level of 3.00 for this functionality.

Assuming you are, log into My Sage Pay, then click the Settings Tab (at the top r/hand side, assuming the user account has privileges to adjust account settings). Then click 'Settings' on the l/hand panel (confusingly!). In the bottom l/hand corner, you have the 'Account Settings' pane.

If you click Edit here, you can then change the page template. Annoyingly, the 'Edit' button might require you to scroll the page down, but it is there.